# Ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException в minecraft 1.8.9

Tags: java, minecraft

Я столкнулся с такой вот ошибкой, я не могу зайти на сервер с моего minecraft клиента (версия 1.8.9), вот полная ошибка `Internal Exception: java.lanu.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.UUID.toString()" beacuse "value" is null`

Cкриншот ошибки https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqGWY.png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вы делаете с UUID в вашем клиенте?

Comment: использую для плащей

Comment: `if(entitylivingbaseIn.getName().equals(Minecraft.getMinecraft().getSession().getUsername()))` @gil9red

Comment: Покажите в вопросе использование UUID, которое привело к ошибке

Comment: а прикол в том, что когда я посмотрел клиет, я нигде не юзал uuid

Comment: У вас там есть что-то про UUID в методе getProfile

Comment: ааа, это я открыл, было в дефолтном майне, я ничего там не трогал

Comment: Не знаю что можно ответить по вашему вопросу, т.к. нет информации. Если ошибка связана с тем, кодом на скриншоте, то смотрите что там происходит и почему к этому приводит. Лучше всего найти логи майнкрафта, ведь наверняка эта ошибка где-то записана, причем в полном виде (вся трасса стека), тогда можно узнать конкретное место возникновения проблемы

Comment: сейчас посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скриншоту, проблема в строках 48-53, конкретно проблема в том, что UUID = null, скорее всего сработало исключение на 51 строчке и у Вас создался GameProfile с uuid = null